# How do I get sound with an HDA card?

Tags: sound, alsa, hda-intel

I have already updated ALSA as described in a related question and tried several other troubleshooting methods - nothing works.
Here is my ALSA info:
http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=7fd485d04c15325cef2409397c7006bbfb92d300

At the end of the info compilations there are some error messages:

```
!!ALSA/HDA dmesg
!!--------------

[    2.941417] cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored
[    2.946434] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    3.049487] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp1s0: link is not ready
--
[    5.966916] RTL871X: set pairwise key to hw: alg:4(WEP40-1 WEP104-5 TKIP-2 AES-4) camid:4
[    5.994800] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: azx_get_response timeout, switching to polling mode: last cmd=0x000f0000
[    6.476281] UpdateHalRAMask8812A => mac_id:0, networkType:0x0b, mask:0x0fffffff
                 ==> rssi_level:1, rate_bitmap:0x0f8f0000
[    7.004035] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, disabling MSI: last cmd=0x000f0000
[    8.013145] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: Codec #0 probe error; disabling it...
[    8.026267] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input9
[    8.026392] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input10
[    8.026454] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input11
[  520.515394] RTL871X: sta recv deauth reason code(3) sta:0c:d6:bd:83:1f:78
```

Anyone with other ideas?

Answer (score 4):

After a long search I've found a solution in here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1525554

open alsa-base.conf as root - e.g.:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

and add the following lines at the end of the file

```
options snd-hda-intel single_cmd=1
options snd-hda-intel probe_mask=1
options snd-hda-intel model=basic
```

and restart - for me sound works perfectly fine now.

You could have the same issue in case

```
dmesg | egrep -i "alsa|snd"
```

gives

> snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, disabling MSI:
>   last cmd=0x000f0000

I have a Realtek ALC671 soundchip BTW. In the system it is called sunrise, with a skylake codec.

Comment: `options snd-hda-intel single_cmd=1` alone fixed it for me (Skylake HD-530, PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog])